# NodeJS: Download 10'000+ Images From Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, download

I need to download 10'000+ images from a server. To do so, i wrote this small script.

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const opt = {
  agent: new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 5
  }),
  headers: {
    'user-agent': 'foo'
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  http.get(`http://www.example.com/${i}.png`, opt, (res) => {
    console.log(i)
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) return
    res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`resource/${i}.png`))
  })
}
```

The problem with this is that after a while i get `Error: read ECONNRESET` or `Error: socket hang up`

I already set `keepAlive: true` and `maxSockets: 5`

My only explanation is that the server has some sort of DOS protection and is blocking my requests?

Any idea how to fix this? Do i need to implement a "cooldown" ?

Comment: You could use `setInterval`, so the page doesn't hang.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to a variable to track which images have returned and how many.

```
var returnedImages = {}
var returnedCount = 0
```

Next you need to wrap that loop in a function, and skip images that have been downloaded already

```
var fetchImgs = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if(returnedImages[i]) continue;
        http.get(`http://www.example.com/${i}.png`, opt, (res) => {
            console.log(i)
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) return
            res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`resource/${i}.png`))
            returnedCount++
        })
    }
}
```

Then you could recursively call that function in a try/catch loop

```
while(returnedCount < 10000) {
    try {
        returnedCount = 0
        fetchImgs()
    } catch(e) {
        if(returnedCount == 0) throw new Error("Cannot fetch anymore")
    }
}
```

The if in the catch block checks if no images were returned and errors out if so (assuming the server is not allowing anymore connections from your ip).

This isnt fool-proof, but you can tweak it to your liking :) 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch processing as mentioned by @Werlious or I would suggest using all your computing power. Since your transaction is atomic and idempotent, you can take advantage of this parallel method and this will scale to more numbers as well.

```
// parent.js
var child_process = require('child_process');

var numchild = require('os').cpus().length;
var done = 0;
var filesListJSON = [{
    "file_name": "Blessed_Titles.jpg",
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/FRDibHa.jpg",
    "downloadId": "6r44r4k340rvvr"
}, {
    "file_name": "Blessed_Titles2.jpg",
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/FRDibHa2.jpg",
    "downloadId": "6r44r4k340rvvr"
}, {
    "file_name": "Blessed_Titles3.jpg",
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/FRDibHa3.jpg",
    "downloadId": "6r44r4k340rvvr"
}];

// split the array into number of parallel threads avalible
var chunks = _.chunk(filesListJSON, numchild);

for (var i = 0; i < numchild; i++) {
    var
    var child = child_process.fork('./child');
    //send the chunk of the list to respective thread. 
    child.send(chunks[i]);
    //ps please check the count and logic for yourself I have not tested this.
    child.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('[parent] received message from child:', message);
        done++;
        if (done === numchild) {
            console.log('[parent] received all results');
      ...
    }
  });
}

// child.js
process.on('message', function (list) {
    console.log('[child] received message from server:', message);
    downloadFiles(list, function (done) {
        console.log("Done  downloading files : " + list.length);
        process.send({
            child: process.pid,
            result: done
        });
        process.disconnect();
    });
});

function downloadFiles(list, cb) {
    //loop over list
    //logic to download files
    //cb(true)
}
```